# How to change Pickmeup jquery datepicker format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pickmeup

I want to change the format of select dates with range using Pickmeup.js, It is great plugin but i am stuck for change its format like:

```
Fri, Nov 25, 2015
```

Is there any solution for change its prefix format to our custom formats in a simple way.

[Reference link for pickmeup.js plugin](https://github.com/nazar-pc/PickMeUp)

Comment: In the Readme it states the format can be change using: `$('.date').pickmeup ({ format  : 'Y-m-d' });`. Am I missing something?

Comment: once read again for format   ::::: Fri, Nov 25, 2015 not like 2015-11-25

Comment: As per the docs, all of `aAbBCdeHIjklmMpPsSuwyY` are supported as date tokens. Put them all in your `format` string and run your program again to find out which ones you want.

Comment: can you add js fiddle working code as  an example

Answer (score 0):

For this case,

```
pickmeup(element,{
    format : 'a, B d, Y'
}
```